# Is dating allowed in Islam?

Tags: relationships

It is essential for anybody to know his or her partner well enough before marriage so that he or she may decide whether to go in matrimonial relation with that person or not. So for that purpose, dating is allowed in Islam or not?

Please don't compare it with love before marriage. Because there's always a possibility that a man is dating some woman just to know her so that he may decide whether she is a right for him or not, but at that moment he hadn't fallen in love with her.

Comment: Well the link you referred to is mainly concerned with "love before marriage", but dating can be different concept because there is a possibility a man is dating some woman just for the sake knowing her then decide whether he should develop feelings for her or not. So your argument regarding duplication is inappropriate.

Comment: I want to know of this new technology that you've developed that let's you develop feelings only when you decide to.

Comment: Buddy, I think you really need experience to know these things. But still I think it is worthwhile to educate someone...first things first...you don't start loving someone at first glance, you take some time to really understand someone and then you decide yourself that whether your feelings are just infatuation or you truly loves that person or is that person right for you so that you may decide whether you indulge yourself toward her or him or just move yourself out of it.

Comment: And dating is basically about meeting new people to let yourself decide not just stick to one in the name of blind love.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'truly love that person' inherently. It is a developed feeling, not a preexisting one. So, in Islam, you develop your love for the person you married instead of marrying the person you developed love for. One is much safer and has legal protections and the other leads to too many emotional, psychological, and legal complications not to mention the power of Shaitan who can easily lead to Zinah. And in the end if you do have irreconcilable differences, divorce is a legal and perfectly acceptable option in Islam.

Answer (score -1):

Dating in its modern term involves lust for the other gender such as kissing, caressing, or having sex. However, it is not haram to investigate the background of the person you may want to marry. It is okay to talk, get to know the other person better, and learn more about them to figure out if you want to marry them or not.

Comment: You need to add your evidences.

Comment: ...and what's the answer to the question?